# Cocoa Error 256 when getting file list in application resources folder

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

The following code is outputting `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)` and the filenames NSArray is null/empty. There should be files in this folder, any ideas whats broken?

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
filenames = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"files" ofType:nil] error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

## EDIT

[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"files" ofType:nil] is returning null for some reason

Comment: "error code 256 can occur when an unknown error is occurred in reading the resource or the path has some encoded characters in it."

Comment: are you trying to go for "files" folder? or is this is a filename of some type?

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer for the path of the files folder. (resources/files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nil extensions aren't folders, iOS treats them like files.  You have to use `-resourcePath` then append the name of your folder instead.

Comment: Got it working again. I had a group but changed it to a folder. I think... Its got a blue icon now anyway. No idea what that means

Comment: Ah!  I see.  Groups in Xcode aren't folders, they are merely graphical representations of a set of files.  The blue folders and finder folder, those are real.  That's how you got it working.